# Tensorflow Issue in the Shortest Path Graph Learning Model of OctavianAI

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, graph-databases, machine-learning-model

I am setting a a Graph Machine Learning application using Ocatvian AI Graph ML toolset. In this particular case, I am trying to setup Shortest Path library. It is failing with error with Tesnforflow backend.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.nn' has no attribute 'rnn_cell'`
```

Please find the detailed error log below :

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>   "main", mod_spec)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>   exec(code, run_globals)
>   File "/Users/gokulalex/Apps/graphml_apps/shortest-path/macgraph/predict.py", line 12, in
>   from .estimator import get_estimator
>   File "/Users/gokulalex/Apps/graphml_apps/shortest-path/macgraph/estimator.py", line 4, in
>   from .model import model_fn
>   File "/Users/gokulalex/Apps/graphml_apps/shortest-path/macgraph/model.py", line 6, in
>   from .cell import execute_reasoning
>   File "/Users/gokulalex/Apps/graphml_apps/shortest-path/macgraph/cell/init.py", line 2, in
>   from .decode import execute_reasoning
>   File "/Users/gokulalex/Apps/graphml_apps/shortest-path/macgraph/cell/decode.py", line 4, in
>   from .mac_cell import *
>   File "/Users/gokulalex/Apps/graphml_apps/shortest-path/macgraph/cell/mac_cell.py", line 14, in
>   class MAC_RNNCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):

Answer (score 0):

As per the investigations into the Tensorflow library in Github and other online forums, it can be understood that the python environment is looking for Tensorflow 2.0 version. However the Octavian AI Shortest Path package seems to be on Tensorflow 1.0.  This seems to be the reason for this build error in training the model.

Please find relevant threads from Tensorflow Github Repository.

[Tensorflow Issue - #32784](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32784)